# Should we have a graphic-novel tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We have 630 questions with the tag [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics). These cover all sorts of comics.

We have questions about comic strips:

[Searching for this comic on bots and humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/98839/51379)

We also have, of course, lots of questions about mainstream comic books, which comprise the majority of these questions. For example, the most recent open question:

[Who's the child and her mother that can "talk to flowers" in Ruins?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132907/whos-the-character-that-can-talk-to-flowers-and-whos-her-daughter-in-ruins)

And we have questions about graphic novels.

A search of the tag [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) with the keywords "graphic novel" brings up 24 results. A search for the keywords alone brings up 52 results, likely indicating that the majority of questions about graphic novels are not tagged as [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics).

Some sources suggest that graphic novels are separate from comics. For example, [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Distinguish-Between-a-Comic-Book-and-a-Graphic-Novel) graphic novels are distinguished mainly by being long-form, or standalone stories. [This](http://dailyutahchronicle.com/2012/09/19/graphic-novels-vs-comic-books-whats-the-difference/) writer takes a similar view, although they also mention aspects of the plot that might be too vague for our purposes.

On the other hand, some people see "graphic novel" as simply a pretentious way of referring to comic books of "quality," a tendency mentioned in some of the answers [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-elitist-to-say-graphic-novel-vs-comic-books-After-all-isnt-a-graphic-novel-technically-a-comic-book).

Note the tag wiki description for [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics), as it stands right now:

> Comics is a graphic medium in which images convey a sequential
>   narrative. The term could include 'graphic-novels'.

This seems to be more a suggestion of a synonym than anything else, but it does put forth the view that the two terms are equivalent.

My interpretation of the term "graphic novel," which I think is fairly close to the mainstream, is basically the same as the first one mentioned: a long-form or standalone graphic work. However, I think graphic novels are a subcategory of comic books, and thus any [graphic-novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-novel) would be a example of [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics).

I see three options:

1. Should we create a [graphic-novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-novel) tag and begin applying it to the relevant questions?
2. Should we create such a tag, but make it a synonym of [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)?
3. Should we not create a [graphic-novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-novel) tag at all, because there is no need for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the overwhelming majority of graphic novels are nothing of the sort. They're simply comics for adults with a fancy name so you'll feel less dumb about buying them. There are some serials that are genuinely "novels in graphic format" but they're very few and far between.

Comment: @Valorum - Yeah, I mention that in my question. I suspect that will be the most popular view. It's not mine, but that's why it's a question and not an answer. ;)

Comment: No, no more tags.....

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No

To quote arch-curmudgeon [Alan Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_novel);

> It [graphic novel] is a marketing term... that I never had any sympathy with. The term
>   'comic' does just as well for me... The problem is that 'graphic
>   novel' just came to mean 'expensive comic book' and so what you'd get
>   is people like DC Comics or Marvel Comics—because 'graphic novels'
>   were getting some attention, they'd stick six issues of whatever
>   worthless piece of crap they happened to be publishing lately under a
>   glossy cover and call it The She-Hulk Graphic Novel....

Given that there's no clear definition of what comprises a graphic novel and what comprises a comic, artificially **dumping a new tag onto those comics that some users consider to be graphic novels** is a waste of time, effort and energy

---

Oh, and as with all of our previous large-scale retagging projects, my standard objections apply:

**1)** How does this actually help anyone (in a demonstrable way)?

**2)** Does this help anyone more than it mucks up the front page?

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm going to hold off on accepting it until someone posts an alternate answer and I see how people vote.